# Selective additional condition in the JOIN

Tags: sql, join, amazon-redshift

```
SELECT id,
       name,
       contact,
       city
FROM table_1
  JOIN table_2
    ON table_1.id = table_2.id
    OR (table_1.age = JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT (property,'age',TRUE)
WHERE table_1.info = 'Employee'
AND   table_1.det = 'A') WHERE id > 10 AND city IN ('abc','def');


SELECT id,
       name,
       contact,
       city
FROM table_1
  JOIN table_2
    ON table_1.id = table_2.id
    OR (table_1.age = JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT (property,'age',TRUE)
AND table_1.info = 'Employee'
AND   table_1.det = 'A') WHERE id > 10 AND city IN ('abc','def');
```

I have a situation where I want the join only when the conditions are met.
I want to know which one of the above would be right way to do it.

Comment: Please include the full actual queries, along with some sample data.

Comment: Hi @Anindita, welcome to Stack Overflow: There is one thing that is not clear here. Please clear to us your question. You say "second join" but you only have one join. When you say "second join" do you mean on the part in the where clause from the first example?

Comment: @Anindita . . . What is the "second" join?  What tables do the columns come from?

Comment: @VBoka My bad. I meant to write the join. I've updated my question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm sorry, I have added a snippet example of the actual data as I couldn't share the actual queries along with the sample data.

Comment: @GordonLinoff There is no second join. It was a miss from my end. The column id and name comes from table_1 whereas contact and city comes from table_2.

Answer (score 0):

First one is better than the second ,because we have restricted in first one query with **WHERE** clause in which if condition met from for 'info,id,city' then only you will get the result.